# In Excel (Mac), how to modify the Legend to include content from multiple columns

Tags: excel, charts, legend

In Office 365 Excel for Mac, I have a simple bar chart showing growth percentage for various entities. The names for each data point that are in the legend are picked up from the first column, but I would like to reformat the legend labels to add content from another column.

Right now, the horizontal axis labels, which is used for the Legend, is selected as follows:

='Current Quarter'!$B$26:$B$43

The B column contains simple strings; in my case, social media handles ( "IndigenousYouth" for example). I am trying to get it to show the content of that column, followed by a space, followed by the open parenthesis, followed by the C column, followed by the closed parenthesis. In other words:

Indigenous Youth (250,509)

The end result would be a legend where each label would be followed by the main current value for it (in parentheses).

How can I edit the axis label text to make this work?

Comment: Create the label text in a cell - I use the &, so =B1&B2&"label text". Then call that cell for the label.

Comment: Thank you!! I should have thought of that! What's worse is, I already have such a column (for some other purpose). I shouldn't really be working when I'm sick...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm putting this as an answer, although it arrived in a comment to the question, because it solves the problem.

The easiest way to achieve this goal is to simply create another column in the table and use a formula to build the text for the legend label as desired:

```
 =B1&" ("&C1&")"
```

This would result in that particular column showing the data from columns B and C formatted specifically:

Column B (Column C)

Then simply pick this new column as the source for the legend. Depending on how the data in these columns is formatted, you may need some additional formatting parameters in the formula, but the beauty is that you have complete flexibility of excel formulas to get any kind of data and formatting that you can then present in charts, as axis or legend labels.